# Web-based RSS feed reader similar to StumbleUpon

Tags: web-apps, feed-reader

I am looking for a web-based (not self-hosted) RSS feed reader application that works similar to [StumbleUpon](http://www.stumbleupon.com/):

- Allows me to add all my RSS feeds
- Randomly picks one entry out of my RSS feeds collection at a time and displays it full-screen on a single page
- Allows me to go back and forth to the previous/next RSS feed entry

More criteria:

- The reader can be a paid service of maximum $2 per month.
- Doesn't need to have a sync service

Reference to the single-page entry design of StumbleUpon:

> [image: StumbleUpon]

Comment: Maybe you could add a few more details: what's your budget (or must it be free)? What OS must be supported (or would a web-app be fine)? Must it have sync services (e.g. Feedly), or shall it be stand-alone? References: [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) / [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Comment: @Izzy Thank you! I improved my question. Please see my edit.

Comment: "can be a paid service": USD 1.000 per day OK – and a service that requires an Atari ST to run on? ;) Clear-text: Please name your budget (e.g. "can be a paid service (but max USD 10 per month)") and whether it should run natively on your desktop (which OS?) or be a web-app (self-hosted?). Thanks!